# How to get a token with signed in user on azure active directory in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web app running in Node.js. It's authentication is integrated with azure active directory. Currently we are using a service principal to make calls to an API registered in the directory. How can i change the token request so it's made by the authenticated user and not by the service principal? This is mainly because all actions after the calls are registered as Service Principal and not by the logged in user.

This is the actual code that i use to request a token and acces the api:

```
var qs = require('qs');
const axios = require('axios');
const Swagger = require("swagger-client");
const request = require("request");
const http = require("https");


const AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_name>';
const WORKBENCH_API_URL = '<api_url>';
const RESOURCE = '<resource_id>';
const CLIENT_APP_Id = '<service_principal_id>';
const CLIENT_SECRET = '<serivce_principal_secret>';


// Getting token from AAD
const acquireTokenWithClientCredentials = async(resource, clientId, clientSecret, authority) => {
  const requestBody = {
    resource: resource,
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  };
  console.log(acquireTokenWithClientCredentials);

  const response = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${authority}/oauth2/token`,
    data: qs.stringify(requestBody),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  });

  return response.data;
}
```

I'm ussing passport-azure-ad strategy with redirects.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently using [client credentials grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), where the token is being acquired using application/service principal identity.

You can change to make use of Authorization Code Grant Flow in order to utilize User's identity to acquire the token and call the relevant API.

**Conceptual Documentation**: [Azure AD Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)

**Node.js Specific Sample**: [Authorization Code Sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#authorization-code)

This sample makes use of [ADAL for Node.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#windows-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal-for-nodejs).

I'm only highlighting the important part here, but the link above gives entire website code on GitHub, along with some pointers about the library that it uses.

```
authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(
    req.query.code,
    redirectUri,
    resource,
    clientId, 
    clientSecret,
    function(err, response) {
      var errorMessage = '';
      if (err) {
        errorMessage = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
      }
      errorMessage += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);
      res.send(errorMessage);
    }
  );
```